# Unable to read error response of fb plugin share

Tags: json, cordova, facebook-graph-api, error-handling, cordova-facebook

I am using `cordova-plugin-facebook4` version 1.7.4 for facebook share in my app. I got an error while sharing one post to facebook.

```
{errorMessage : "Facebook error: {FacebookServiceException: httpResponseCode: -1, facebookErrorCode: 190, facebookErrorType: null, message: Error validating access token: The user has not authorized application XXXXXXXX.}" }
```

From the facebook docs, I came to know that this error occurs when user de-authorizes my app. So I want to login again and obtain a new access token.

In the [Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/debugging-and-error-handling), I came to know that facebook sends error code 190 when this error occurs. I am able to see the `facebookErrorCode` field in my error response.

My problem is I am unable to parse the error response to get the facebook error code. I tried few JSON parse and JSON stringify methods. But nothing worked. I am unable to obtain the error code.

Can anyone help me in parsing the error response and getting the error code ?

**UPDATE**

Here is my code sample

```
facebookConnectPlugin.showDialog( 
            { method: "share_open_graph",
                action: 'og.likes',
                object: JSON.stringify({
                  object:'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
              })
            }, 
            function (response) { 
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response)); 
                DialogService.showToast('FB_SHARE_SUCCESS', 'Short', 'Bottom');
                
            },
            function (response) { 
                console.log('share failed. ',response);
                if(response.errorMessage.facebookErrorCode == 190){
                    fblogin.then(
                        function(response){
                            share();
                        },
                        function(error){
                            //
                        }
                    )
                }else{
                    DialogService.showToast('FB_SHARE_FAILED', 'Short', 'Bottom');
                } 
                
            }
        );
```

I am able to post to facebook if the user authorizes the app for posting.
If the user de-authorizes, I am unable to capture the error code 190.

Comment: Can you edit your post and add the code that you wrote (with the call to facebook and error callback) please ?

Comment: @e666 I updated my question.

Comment: And which line print the error ? It seems that it is this one `console.log('share failed. ',response);` but it is missing the share failed. If it is exacly this one the lib has done really bad thing with JSON and you will have to parse the error via Regex or split string and not JSON....